# Remove words from link using a:visited once a link has been clicked

Tags: css

is there a way with pure css to Have a link that might say "New! Watch Video" and then once someone has clicked the link have it remove the "New" portion of the link. I'm assuming this can be done w/ Jquery but I'd like to see if there is an way to remove it with just css.

Comment: Using the :visited selector won't work; this much is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than removing words, add the word "New" if the link *hasn't* been visited yet

```
a:before {
    content: "New! ";
}
a:visited:before {
    content: "";
}
```

No extra markup, and you don't need to put the word "New" everywhere.

Comment: If you wanted, you could apply it only to links with a certain class, e.g. `a.video:before { ... }` or only links within a certain region of the page `div.videos a:before { ... }`

Comment: i like the a:before solution. I had a feeling there was something i could do with pseudo selectors. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the "New!" in a span inside the anchor:

```
<a class="newText" href="somepage.html"><span>New! </span>Watch video</a>
```

and in your CSS, set:

```
a.newText:visited span { display: none; }
```

I would recommend using a class on the anchor (like "newText" above) so that this formatting will only be applied to the links you want it on. And keep in mind that the "New!" text will reappear if the user clears their browser history.

Comment: This doesn't, in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04, work. I'm assuming that it's to prevent browser history sniffing via the styling of `a:visited` links. [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9YPnE/).

Comment: Well in that case, gotta use JS.

Comment: I believe, for usability reasons, you can only change the color using :visited.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the anchor will take you to a new page you can use the following technique:

```
a:before {
    content: "New! ";
}
```

On any page you wish to remove or change it, you can add a body class

```
body.blah a:before {
    content: "";
}
```